# Netbeans error for C++: Build Host is not connected

Tags: c++, netbeans

I've installed NetBeans on Ubuntu 19.04 with this command

```
sudo apt-get install netbeans
```

Then, installed C++ plugins, restarted, create a simple  hello world project from samples. Nothing is shown, no project listed. I've checked the project directory and saw that the project is opened and `.cc` and  `.h` files and others are there.

When I dig into, I've found out that `Tools->Options->C++` shows 
     Local host

g++, gcc are installed and they are in

```
$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
```

I've tried to adding `/usr/inlcude/c++/8` into the `$PATH` but nothing changed.

How can I properly install the C++ plugins?

**Note:** a Java application works correctly.

Comment: Netbeans 10? It has not official C++ support. https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb112/index.html

Comment: @adasiko yes Netbeans 10. I see we need to `go to the Plugin Manager, enable the NetBeans IDE 8.2 Update Center, which lets you install the NetBeans IDE 8.2 modules providing C and C++ features.` but couldn't see that in the plugins.